# Cucumber. How to enable code completion for RSpec assertions in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, rubymine

I use Cucumber with Rspec assertions.

Their [documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/checking-assertions/) says:

> Add the `rspec-expectations` gem to your Gemfile. Cucumber will automatically load RSpec’s matchers and expectation methods to be available in your step definitions.

It works fine but RubyMine 2020.1 can't recognize RSpec and code autocompletion in steps definition doesn't work as expected:

```
Given /^a nice new bike$/ do
  expect(@bikes).to have_key("new")
end
```

IDE doesn't suggest `expect` when I start typing exp... and `have_key` is underlined with a warning `Cannot find have_key`.
Is it possible to make this feature work?

Comment: Added [tag:rubymine] since this really has nothing to do with ruby, rspec, or cucumber specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment RubyMine doesn't have support for it. Please add your vote and follow the corresponding request:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-26444